# How to create PDF (large) in with memory efficiency in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a Pdf consist of page around 30(merely 2mb), but the app used to receive memory warning and crashes often. 
I used to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions for getting some images, also renderInContext for taking image of xibs and write to files.

**sample code**

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
                        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                        imageView.image = nil;
                        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
                        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Screen_%d%@",item,imageNumber];
                        NSString  *pngPath = PDFTempResourceDirectory();
                        pngPath = [pngPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
                        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

Below are the codes which i used for creating the pdf

```
 -(void)setPDFOutPutPath:(NSString*)path{

NSString *pdfPathOutput = [PDFFileDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",path]];
CFURLRef pdfURLOutput = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPathOutput isDirectory:NO];
writeContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(pdfURLOutput, NULL, NULL);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(writeContext,kCGInterpolationNone);
pdfPathOutput = nil;
}


-(void)appendPDfFile:(NSString *)path{

CFURLRef pdfURL;
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfRef;
NSInteger numberOfPages;
CGPDFPageRef page;
CGRect mediaBox;

pdfURL = (__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
pdfRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL);
numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfRef);

for (int i=1; i<=numberOfPages; i++) {
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfRef, i);
    mediaBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
    CGContextBeginPage(writeContext, &mediaBox);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page);
    CGContextEndPage(writeContext);
}
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfRef);
}
```

for creating pdf

///

```
(void)createSinglePDF:(CALayer *)inputView with:(int)pageNumber{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, firstPage.bounds, nil);
        CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        [inputView renderInContext:pdfContext];
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
//        if(pdfContext)
//            CGContextClearRect(pdfContext, firstPage.bounds);
//        if(pdfContext)
//            CGContextFlush(pdfContext);
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PDFReport_%d.pdf",pageNumber];
        NSString *documentDirectoryFilename = [PDFFileDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        BOOL isSaved =[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
        NSString *pdfPath  = [PDFFileDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PDFReport_%d.pdf",pageNumber]];
        [self appendPDfFile:pdfPath];
            // CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
       // CGContextRelease(pdfContext);
    }
```

}

Comment: it's not clear how your 3 blocks of code are all interacting. None of the function names are being called from the other blocks of code. Are you calling the first block of code 30 times? More context is required to understand how you are ending up with a large PDF that is causing memory problems.

Comment: Each xib is filled with data, and i create a pdf of that xib and used to combine all these pdf, with the help of this - i have added that code to above question